# server running- mysqladmin error- Development Source Tree

Tags: mysql, mysqladmin

I'm frustrated!
I have installed mysql using Development Source Tree(version 5.7.5) in Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit.

### Starting

- I started mysql in *safe mode* using:

  ```
  mysqlnew@dpaks:~$ mysqld_safe &
  [1] 4548
  mysqlnew@dpaks:~$ 141024 11:18:58 mysqld_safe Logging to'/usr/local/mysql/data/dpaks.err'.
  141024 11:18:58 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
  ```

  However, on entering *'mysqladmin version'*, I get the following error:

  ```
  mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
  error: 'Access denied for user 'deepaks'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
  ```
- If I give a prefix '--skip-grant-tables', mysqladmin starts and gives the following:

  > mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.7.5-m15, for Linux on i686
  >
  > Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
  >
  > Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
  >   affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
  >   owners.
  >
  > Server version        5.7.5-m15
  >
  > Protocol version  10
  >
  > Connection        Localhost via UNIX socket
  >
  > UNIX socket       /tmp/mysql.sock
  >
  > Uptime:           7 sec
  >
  > Threads: 1  Questions: 2  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 84  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 79  Queries per second avg: 0.285

  So, what is happening with the *grants table*?

**Permissions:**

- For the purpose of running mysql, I created a user as well as a group by the name mysqlnew.
- My entire installation at /usr/local/mysql is owned by mysqlnew. Permissions 
  were set to 777 recursively for the entire directory except for the data directory.
- Data directory was given 744.
- *my.cnf* was set to 755 for user mysqlnew. Its temp file was owned by root.
- *mysql.sock* had permissions 777

**Server is running?** **Yes, it is!**

Its listed in process status.

```
mysqlnew  5022  4341  0 12:22 pts/8    00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe
mysqlnew  5154  5022  3 12:22 pts/8    00:00:00 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/dpaks.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/dpaks.pid --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock --port=3306
```

Also, the netstat command gave me the following:

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                     LISTEN      4680/mysqld
```

**Error Log**
The *error log* says the following:

```
2014-10-24T05:49:00.835656Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.5 started; log sequence number 1296682
2014-10-24T05:49:00.854718Z 0 [Warning] Failed to setup SSL
2014-10-24T05:49:00.854736Z 0 [Warning] SSL error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2014-10-24T05:49:00.854757Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
2014-10-24T05:49:00.854795Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2014-10-24T05:49:00.864657Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2014-10-24T05:49:01.399455Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2014-10-24T05:49:01.399499Z 0 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.5-m15'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

which means that server is running! Right?

**Conf file** Following is an excerpt from my *my.cnf* file located in etc directory:

```
[client]

port=3306
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock

[mysqld]

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES 
user = mysql
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

I also **verified** that mysql.sock is being created in /tmp directory.

**Question**: Why am I getting an error when I start mysqladmin without using the prefix '--skip-grant-tables' while the server is running?

Any help would be wholeheartedly appreciated

**PS**: I have read thoroughly and tried all the solutions given in similar questions here but to no avail.

---

### Update 1

When I gave --skip-grants-table and then when ran 'mysql', its working! But why should I skip it?

Comment: looks like it tries to connect using SSL (https://) for which it does not have a certificate, but this could not be it, it is only a warning.

Comment: @joelharkes Yes, its just a warning and I believe SSL is not required for communication between client and server in the same system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG! I can't believe I solved it!

I started mysqld. However, client could not be started. When I gave the command 'mysql', the following error was shown:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>   mysqlnew@dpaks:/usr/local/mysqlnew/bin$ ./mysql

Why not create a user account in mysql?! Hence, I created a user account 'root' with 'root' as the password by writing the following in a text file named *init-file* and placing it where the user *mysqlnew* have access right. Note that they must be in different lines. Also, ensure that the server is not running.

> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('root') WHERE User='root';
>   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

I started the server by:

> ./mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysqlnew --datadir=/usr/local/mysqlnew/data --query_cache_type=1 --init-file=/home/mysqlnew/init-file &

I then started the client by

> mysqlnew@dpaks:/usr/local/mysqlnew/bin$ ./mysql -u root -p
>   Enter password:

Since I have now created a user account in mysql, I don't need to use *--skip-grant-tables* anymore for starting server.

However, its not yet finished!

> mysql> select 1+1;
>   ERROR 1820 (HY000): You must SET PASSWORD before executing this statement

So, now I need to rectify this!

> mysql> SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('root');
>   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.28 sec)

And that is it! :)